# Confused between andriod.app.Fragment and layout.Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two separate buttons which displays separate fragments upon click.
This is my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.sjha.myapplication.MainActivity">

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal">
      <Button
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/fragment_one"
          android:text="Fragment1"/>

      <Button
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/fragment_two"
          android:text="Fragment2"/>



  </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <fragment
            android:name="layout.FragmentOne"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/fragment">


        </fragment>



    </LinearLayout>




</LinearLayout>
```

I am lost somewhere between `android.app.Fragment` and `layout.Fragment`.Please help me fix this.

This is my java file.

```
package com.example.sjha.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;

import layout.FragmentOne;
import layout.FragmentTwo;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void changeFragment(View v)
    {
        Fragment fragment;
        if (v==findViewById(R.id.fragment_one))
        {
            //HERE IS THE ERROR..
            //I AM LOST BETWEEN android.app.Fragment and layout.Fragment
            //FragmentTwo() is layout.Fragment while fragment is android.app.Fragment

            fragment= new FragmentTwo();
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment, fragment);
            ft.commit();

        }
    }
}
```

How do i fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch. When clicking on buttons, you can't look for `Fragment`'s in your layout as they might not added yet. A better way is to check button IDs.

Reconstruct your method that reacts to `onClick` event of buttons and for choosing fragmment based on Button id:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
   Fragment fragment = new FragmentOne();
   switch (view.getId) {
      case R.id.fragment_one:
      break;
      case R.id.fragment_one:
      fragment = new FragmentTwo();
      break;
   }
   FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
   FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
   ft.replace(R.id.fragment, fragment);
   ft.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define your fragment in a Static way (inside your layout) you can't replace/delete it with a fragment transaction.
if you want to swap between fragments, use the Dynamic way where you have to use a holder for your fragment, use FrameLayout, and then you can work with the `fragmentTransaction` to replace fragments.

You have more information and code examples in those links:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

http://coreylatislaw.com/managing-static-and-dynamic-fragments/